# Place map legends and titles in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, symbology

I am new to GeoServer and tried to learn from basics and be familiar with GIS concepts. I published a shapefile in GeoServer, now I want to add a title and legend to the published file.

Please advise me the solution.

Comment: What do you mean by Title & Legend? These thing have a very different meaning when it comes to printed maps, and web maps. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Title means i want to show name of the layer and legend means the legend of a layer

Comment: where do you want to show it?

Comment: Maybe i understand question wrong but if you want publish your layers in web you can use GeoExt. http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/layercontainer.html http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/legendpanel.html